# Is there a way to persist theme changes between pages? [Material UI]

Tags: javascript, css, material-ui, material-design, themes

When using MUI 5.14.1, I am receiving an error whenever I try to persist themes through pages using localStorage. I'd appreciate any help on how I might fix this, or advice on how I could go about this differently.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  CssBaseline,
  Button,
  Typography,
} from "@mui/material";
import { ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material/styles";
import { Toaster, toast } from "react-hot-toast";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom"; // Import the Link component from react-router-dom
import styles from "../styles/app.module.css";
import MuteSwitch from "../components/MuteSwitch.js";
import StyledAvatar from "../components/StyledAvatar.js";
import Sidebar from "../components/Sidebar";
import {
  toggleDarkMode,
  handleThemeChange,
  lightTheme,
} from "../utils/themeUtils";

const persistedTheme = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("theme")) || lightTheme;
const HomePage = () => {
  const [currentTheme, setCurrentTheme] = useState(persistedTheme); // Define the state variable for the current theme
  const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = useState(false); // Track dark mode state, false = light mode, true = dark mode
  const [userInputColor, setUserInputColor] = useState("#1976d2"); // Default initial color
  const [colorPickerColor, setColorPickerColor] = useState("#1976d2"); // Default initial color

  const saveTheme = (theme) => {
    localStorage.setItem("theme", JSON.stringify(currentTheme));
  };

  const handleColorChange = (event) => {
    setColorPickerColor(event.target.value);
    setUserInputColor(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleDarkModeToggle = () => {
    setDarkMode((prevMode) => !prevMode); // Toggle the dark mode state
    toggleDarkMode(darkMode, setCurrentTheme);
  };

  const createToast = (message) => {
    let toastBackground = currentTheme.palette.primary.main;
    let toastColor = currentTheme.palette.primary.contrastText;
    toast.success(message, {
      style: {
        background: toastBackground,
        color: toastColor,
      },
    });
  };
  const handleNewMessages = () => {
    createToast("You have 3 new messages");
  };

  const onThemeChange = () => {
    //possibly darken color picker color
    const updatedTheme = handleThemeChange(userInputColor);
    setCurrentTheme(updatedTheme);
    saveTheme(updatedTheme);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Toaster />

      <ThemeProvider theme={currentTheme}>
        <CssBaseline />

        <div className={styles.heading}>
          <Typography variant="h1" component="h1" gutterBottom>
            Home Page
          </Typography>
        </div>

        {/* content */}
        <div className={styles.centeredContent}>
          <Button variant="contained">Pretty Colors</Button>
        </div>
        {/* mute switch */}
        <div className={styles.muteSwitch}>
          <MuteSwitch />
        </div>
        {/* avatar */}
        <Link to="/profile" style={{ textDecoration: "none", color: "inherit" }}>
        <div className={styles.avatar}>
          <StyledAvatar>TS</StyledAvatar>
        </div>
        </Link>

        {/* drawer */}
        <div>
          <Sidebar handleThemeChange={onThemeChange} darkMode={darkMode} handleDarkModeToggle={handleDarkModeToggle} handleNewMessages={handleNewMessages} colorPickerColor={colorPickerColor} handleColorChange={handleColorChange}/>
        </div>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </>
  );
};

export default HomePage;
```

Error:

```
Unexpected Application Error!
theme.transitions.create is not a function
TypeError: theme.transitions.create is not a function
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:11135:35
```

I tried using localStorage to store it, expecting it to let me retrieve the theme in the new file, but whenever I edit `const [currentTheme, setCurrentTheme] = useState(lightTheme);` to use the persisted theme it gives me an error.

EDIT: This has now been solved. Consider using my solution, which uses React Context, or Dewaun Ayers' solution (marked as solution in the replies), which uses localStorage.

My solution:

Create a file called "ThemeContext.js", or something similar, which contains the following:

```
// ThemeContext.js

import { createContext, useContext, useState } from "react";
import { createTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";

const ThemeContext = createContext();

export const useThemeContext = () => {
  return useContext(ThemeContext);
};

export const ThemeContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [currentTheme, setCurrentTheme] = useState(lightTheme);

  const handleThemeChange = (color) => {
    const secondaryColor = color; //edit this to be your secondary color
    const newTheme = createTheme({
      palette: {
        primary: {
          main: color,
        },
        secondary: {
          main: secondaryColor,
        },
      },
    });

    setCurrentTheme(newTheme);
  };


  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider
      value={{ currentTheme, handleThemeChange }}
    >
      {children}
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Import this file into your top level React file, and wrap your router/components in the ThemeContextProvider component. My implementation as as follows:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "./index.css";
import HomePage from "./pages/HomePage";
import ProfilePage from "./pages/ProfilePage";
import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";
import { ThemeContextProvider } from "./utils/ThemeContext";

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <HomePage />,
  },
  {
    path: "/profile",
    element: <ProfilePage />,
  },
]);

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <ThemeContextProvider>
      <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </ThemeContextProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Finally, edit your page components to use the variables and functions stored in Context, like below:

```
import { useThemeContext } from "../utils/ThemeContext";

const HomePage = () => {
  const { currentTheme, handleThemeChange, isDarkMode, toggleDarkMode, colorPickerColor, userInputColor, handleColorChange } = useThemeContext();

  const createToast = (message) => {
    let toastBackground = currentTheme.palette.primary.main;
    let toastColor = currentTheme.palette.primary.contrastText;
    toast.success(message, {
      style: {
        background: toastBackground,
        color: toastColor,
      },
    });
  };
  const handleNewMessages = () => {
    createToast("You have 3 new messages");
  };

  const onThemeChange = () => {
    //possibly darken color picker color
    handleThemeChange(userInputColor);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Toaster />

      <ThemeProvider theme={currentTheme}>
        <CssBaseline />

        <div className={styles.heading}>
          <Typography variant="h1" component="h1" gutterBottom>
            Home Page
          </Typography>
        </div>

        {/* content */}
        <div className={styles.centeredContent}>
          <Button variant="contained">Pretty Colors</Button>
        </div>
        {/* mute switch */}
        <div className={styles.muteSwitch}>
          <MuteSwitch />
        </div>
        {/* avatar */}
        <Link
          to="/profile"
          style={{ textDecoration: "none", color: "inherit" }}
        >
          <div className={styles.avatar}>
            <StyledAvatar>TS</StyledAvatar>
          </div>
        </Link>

        {/* drawer */}
        <div>
        <Sidebar
            handleThemeChange={onThemeChange}
            isDarkMode={isDarkMode}
            handleDarkModeToggle={toggleDarkMode}
            handleNewMessages={handleNewMessages}
            colorPickerColor={colorPickerColor}
            handleColorChange={handleColorChange}
            currentTheme={currentTheme}
          />
        </div>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </>
  );
};

export default HomePage;
```

This commit to the project repository shows the full changes:
https://github.com/AnthonySchneider2000/React-Material-UI-Dynamic-Theme-Changer/commit/5e89229b8ec04e2cc3aed3b7fc7205b1396ee401

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track for persisting the theme to local storage.

I think you are seeing that error because either:

You aren't `creating a theme` the MUI way by using the `createTheme` function, passing it a valid theme object, then passing that to the `ThemeProvider`

OR

You are creating a valid theme in your imported theme files and the functions (like `transitions.create`) are destroyed when you stringify the theme object before saving to local storage.

If it's the second reason, the description for JSON.stringify() states:

> `undefined`, `Function`, and `Symbol` values are not valid JSON values. If
> any such values are encountered during conversion, they are either
> omitted (when found in an object) or changed to `null` (when found in an
> array). `JSON.stringify()` can return `undefined` when passing in "pure"
> values like `JSON.stringify(() => {})` or `JSON.stringify(undefined)`.

Ideally, you will want to only store the theme values in local storage (before passing it into `createTheme`), or a token that represents the selected theme and use that to pick which theme to show the user.

I created [this Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-ganguly-r3mmnm) to demonstrate a different way of switching themes while also persisting to local storage.

Hope this answers your question!